# Add fadeIn effect to image container hyperlink append string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the gallery:

```
<div id="gallery">
   <a href="images/gallery/big/01.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/01.jpg"></a>
   <a href="images/gallery/big/02.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/02.jpg"></a>
   <a href="images/gallery/big/03.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/03.jpg"></a>
   <a href="images/gallery/big/04.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/04.jpg"></a>
   <a href="images/gallery/big/05.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/05.jpg"></a>
   <a href="images/gallery/big/06.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/06.jpg"></a>
   <a href="images/gallery/big/07.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/07.jpg"></a>
   <a href="images/gallery/big/08.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/08.jpg"></a>
   <button class="more">show me more</button>
</div>
```

It shows 8 images by default, and there is a button to load more:

```
var num = 8;
var incr = 4;
$(function() {
    $('button.more').click(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < incr; i++){
        num++;
        var a = $('<a class="photo"></a>')
            .attr('href', 'images/gallery/big/' + padLeft(num.toString(), '0', 2) + '.jpg');
        var img = $('<img alt="" />')
            .attr('src', 'images/gallery/' + padLeft(num.toString(), '0', 2) + '.jpg');         
        a.append(img);
        a.insertBefore($(this));
    }
    if (num > 15){
   $(".more").hide();
    }
});
});

function padLeft(str, pad, len) {
var val = str;

while (val.length < len)
    val = pad + val;    

return val;
}
```

When I add the `.fadeIn(1000)` just after the `a.append(img)`, the new added image container hyperlinks fail to show the image.

Here is the case in action: **http://jsfiddle.net/9b2Ut/3**

Comment: Are you trying to fadein something that is not yet attached to the DOM?

Comment: update ur fiddle with `fadeIn(1000)`

Comment: check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/9b2Ut/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see my updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rynhe/9b2Ut/1/)

After `fadein` jQuery set `display:inline` to the element so u have to give `display: inline-block !important;` for `#gallery a`

Answer (score 0):

First, add display:none to your anchor:

`var a = $('<a style="display:none" class="photo"></a>')`

second, placement of the fadeIn should come after appending:

```
a.append(img);
a.insertBefore($(this));
a.fadeIn(1000);
```

It should also be pointed out that you shouldn't start fading an element in that hasn't been inserted into the DOM yet, that's why I moved the call to **after** the insertBefore call

Comment: Could you make an update on the fiddle? I couldn't make yours.